# Prestashop override FrontControllerCore class from custom module

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want to override Prestashop FrontControllerCore class from my custom module. So can someone tell me how to override FrontControllerCore class from custom module. I am using Prestashop 1.6.

Comment: Check here under `Overriding a class` http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Overriding+default+behaviors

Answer (score 0):

In your module add a new file
`override/classes/controller/FrontController.php`

and add this content

```
class FrontController extends FrontControllerCore
{
    //.. override methods
}
```

Comment: Then how to use that `FrontController` which has been created inside the module from the plugin php file?

Comment: You should copy the original method from classes/controller/FrontController.php and modify it